# how to update sql column(s) when column-names are not known in advance WITHOUT dynamic sql

Tags: sql-server, sql

SQl Server 2008

example:

on the page to edit user profile settings like DOB, gender, name etc..., I wouldn't know which columns user wanted me to update. Should I pass in all these values to the stored procedure, and update all of the profile columns values even though the user may have changed only one or two of them? It seems a little bad, is it?

Using dynamic sql is not an option due to security concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a stored procedure that has default parameters set to null. Then just supply the parameters that you want to change. In the `update` statement, check for null values like this `Age = isnull(@Age, Age)`.

See the example below:

```
-- sample table
    create table UserProfile
    (
        ID int identity(1,1),
        UserName nvarchar(10),
        Gender char(1),
        Age int
    )

    insert into UserProfile values('Bob', 'M', 19)
    insert into UserProfile values('June', 'F', 23)

-- stored proc    
    create proc UpdateUser
    ( 
        @ID int,
        @UserName nvarchar(10) = null,
        @Gender char(1) = null,
        @Age int = null
    )
    as
    begin
        update UserProfile set
            UserName = isnull(@UserName, UserName),
            Gender = isnull(@Gender, Gender),
            Age = isnull(@Age, Age) 
        where ID = @ID
    end

-- usage:    
    exec UpdateUser @ID=1, @Age=29
    exec UpdateUser @ID=1, @UserName='Bill'
    exec UpdateUser @ID=2, @UserName='Julie', @Age=24
    exec UpdateUser @ID=2, @UserName='Mitch', @Gender='M', @Age=56

    select * from UserProfile
```

Answer (score 1):

You could employ a pattern where you have all of your fields be parameters to the stored procedure and have the default values for the parameters be sentinel values outside the domain for the fields (respectively).  Then you write an update statement like:

```
update table
set 
   age = case when @age = -1 then age else @age end,
   weight = case when @weight = -1 then weight else @weight end,
   ...
```

You could accomplish something similar with the fields as parameters and one additional bitfield parameter which would specify whether a given column was updated or not.  That would go something like this:

```
update table
set 
   age = case when @updated & 0x01 then @age else age end,
   weight = case when @updated = 0x02 then @weight else weight end,
   ...
```

They both have their pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to update tables based on the column number of anything like that.  You would have to use dynamic SQL to do this.  If done correctly with parametrized queries, loginless users, execute as and sp_executesql the risks can removed.

Comment: okay, but how do you feel about updating all columns when user intended to update only 2-3?

Comment: That should OK, SQL will actually know that there's no data change and won't actually make a change if the data hasn't changed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see that it matters. If you need to write the stored proc to update any one column, then it shouldn't really matter if you are updating one, or all columns. I'd be surprised if you faced major performance implications by writing several columns of information rather than just one.

If you are concerned about updating data unnecessarily (ie. when nothing has really changed but the user clicked save anyway), and potentially messing with audit triggers etc then look at ways to detect that the user actually modified a value on your form compared to what was originally read from the database by marking the data as dirty